# How to enable inline editing option of a custom field in jira

Tags: jira

Sorry if this is an obvious thing in jira. I have created a Select List type custom field and configured with few create issue and view issue screens.
Now I need this field inline editable. How can I achieve this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the field to the **edit issue** screen.

For the sake of completeness: Also **Inline edit** has to be activated in Administration -> General Configuration.

Comment: I have already enable it by using administrative options but the thing is the newly created field is not responding for inline editing.

Comment: Can you edit the field the when going over "edit issue" (without inline editing)?

Comment: great now its now working..like you said it should be in the edit screen also for enable inline edit or normal editing.thanks Seb...